# How to distinguish the context of requests?

Tags: php, http

is there any chance to distinguish a source of an incoming requests in PHP. For example we can rely on HTTP_HOST value. But it looks not so reliable for me. To be clear, the main idea is that I want to know if person makes a request from the context of mine site or from the others(in case if people will share links, for example on forums) and especially in case if requests are coming from handmade programs to hack the site. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: You want to differentiate between internal and external requests? Then maybe for each request record the IP?

Comment: There are no definate way to identify where a link, used by a browser, came from. You can only make a best guess. Also see the `$_SERVER` variable `HTTP_REFERER`.

Comment: When people arrive to your site from links on other sites, they will simply load a link to one of your resources, meaning the request will still come from your own site essentially. Although the source might be revealed by HTTP_REFERER (not entirely reliable though).

Comment: Thanks to everybody! You are right, I also think so, that it's only a chance to guess a referer cause all headers can be sabstituted.

Comment: As for detecting automated requests, I think that's more a question of server management. You could analyse variables like HTTP_USER_AGENT, but that can also be manipulated, so the only reliable way is to make your application secure (to any type of request), and have a well-enough managed server that things like unusual spikes in traffic from a given IP or to a certain resource are detected and managed accordingly.

Comment: what about checking a $_SESSION var? If the request originates on your site then create a var. Check this var with each request.